# Can't boot truecrypt's rescue.iso on usb using UNetBootin

Tags: boot, truecrypt

I tried Unetbootin to put the `truecrypt rescue.iso` file on a USB stick, but the USB stick does not boot properly.

It gets into an infinite loop with boot default in 10 seconds over and over again.

The default setting is: `/ubnkern initrd=/ubninit`.

Comment: @kobaltz HOw did you get truecrypt rescue working?

Comment: I recommend flashboot. Flashboot worked.But rufus, PowerISO, PenDriveLinux they all failed.

Answer (score 1):

I have had all sorts of problems with Unetbootin. Try [PenDriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) instead to create your USB from an ISO image. In the last 1-2 years I have only gotten 1 distro to boot from a USB created with Unetbootin. However on the other hand I have had a 100% success rate with PenDriveLinux

Comment: Does it work with truecrypt? It does not work for me. No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!

Comment: or just use dd: dd if=/path-to-truecrypt-image.iso of=/path-to-usb-stick

Comment: Have you actually succeeded with dd? I did not get a bootable usb drive as a result.

Comment: @ptman dd works with most linux iso. I tried to make a bootable windows usb but failed.